# How I can I detect all ImageViews that have been touched in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am trying to make a "Dots" clone and am having difficulty trying to figure out how to detect all imageviews that have been touched with one swipe of the finger. I believe I should be using a viewgroup but not sure where to go from there, any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: so touched or swiped? disjoint actions could be assigned to both events

Comment: They clearly mean collision detection from a swipe. Be nice to new users! User asking the question, you need to show us what you've tried already though. This isn't a freelancer forum and people don't get paid to write your app for you

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could do this - here's one of them.

Create a RelativeLayout and give it an id. In your activity class, find this RelativeLayout and set an `OnTouchListener` on it.

Now populate a 2d array that contains your image views and add them to your RelativeLayout.

In the `OnTouch` callback method, you'll have access to a `MotionEvent` object that you can query to access motion events that describe the user's finger location as it moves across the screen. Compare the provided x and y coordinates to the x and y locations of the image views in your 2d array and if the coordinates match those of an image view, then add the selected image view to an ArrayList.

```
 float x,y; //lets say these are populated with a point/average on your swipe path
 View element = ... ; //view representing one item in your array
 if ( x > element.getX() && x < element.getX() + element.getWidth() ) {
     //Collides with x axis, check y axis now
        //if that also colides, save this element in a set/list
 }
```

When the user lifts his/her finger from the screen, all of the selected image views will be stored in the ArrayList.

Comment: Good answer, I'm going to add a snippet of code, don't take offence, it will just help newer users with a common problem